# Does ADAL.js support integrated windows authentication or client credential flow?

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling, adal

I am trying to call Graph API from my SPFx webpart (in SharePoint 2019 on-premise) using ADAL.js. It works fine but user needs to sign-in to Azure AD once. Our on-premise AD is already synched with Azure AD.

We don't want users to see the 'Sign-In' button (to call the graph api). Users should be authenticated automatically as they are already connected with on-premise AD.

Does adal.js/msal.js supports Implicit flow only or integrated windows authentication is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it is not clearly stated in the documentation at this point, the ability to connect (and have authentication and authorization) automatically to AAD secured APIs (including the Microsoft Graph) **is limited to SharePoint online only**.
This is because SharePoint Online registers AAD applications, declares and approves the permissions/scopes behind the scenes, this is something SharePoint on prem (2016 or 2019) can't do today.